# How to make sql insert string from data entered into JTextField

Tags: java, mysql, sql, user-interface

im having some problems getting the insert string to work its giving me a syntax error but cant figure out why, any help ?

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO user VALUES ('"+ jtfEmailAddr.getText()+"'," + 
             "'"+ jtfPassword2.getText() + "'," + 
             "'"+ jtfFName.getText() +"','" + jtfSurname.getText() +"')" +
             "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE password='" + jtfPassword2.getText() + "'"+ `enter code here`
             "firstname='" + jtfFName.getText() + "'," +
             "lastname='" + jtfSurname.getText() + "'";
database.insertIntoDatabase(sql);
```

ERROR:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'rr'nn)' at line 1
```

the letters rr nn are just random for test purposed

Comment: Why dont you share the error, it would be usefull for everybody to help...

Comment: Anyway... the part “enter code here” doesnt seem correct

Comment: thats not in my code it only appeared when i entered it on this site so ignore that lol

Comment: It seems a missing comma just before that text, in the password2 string

Comment: Can you print out the sql before calling insertIntoDatabase. It would help with spotting the issue.

Comment: Please use a prepared statement. It will be safer and will send input as values rather than as inline query parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Try adding a comma there “‘,”
With no more information is the part I see wrong
(Apart from of course the the “enter code here”...)

Comment: thanks so much it worked, was struggling at this for hours thanks